# Validate android app certificate

Tags: android, security, certificate, x509, signature

I want to check if installed android application has self signed or trusted certificate. The problem is that my code listed below raises CertificateException for all installed (including Google made) apps. Could you help me to find a problem why it doesn't work correctly?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    List<ResolveInfo> runningServices = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCaStore");
    ks.load(null, null);
    tmf.init(ks);
    X509TrustManager trustManager = (X509TrustManager)tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    try {
        for (ResolveInfo runningService : runningServices) {
            PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo(runningService.activityInfo.packageName,
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

            Signature signature = info.signatures[0];
            Signature[] arrSignatures = info.signatures;
            for (Signature sig : arrSignatures) {
                byte[] rawCert = sig.toByteArray();
                InputStream certStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawCert);

                CertificateFactory certFactory;
                X509Certificate x509Cert;
                try {
                    certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
                    x509Cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(certStream);
                    trustManager.checkServerTrusted(new X509Certificate[] { x509Cert }, "RSA");
                }
                catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (CertificateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty obvious: we can't validate android app certificate using trusted certificates chain (what normally do ssl guts to check web resource certificate), because they are self-signed. That is why checkServerTrusted function raises CertificateException during such check. This [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430246804) gives following information:

> Because a process is tied to a package name, and a package name is
>   tied to its signature, signatures play a role in securing the data
>   belonging to a package. A package is typically signed with a
>   self-signed PKI (Public Key Infrastructure) certificate. A certificate
>   identifies who the author of the package is. These certificates need
>   not be issued by a certificate authority. This means the information
>   in the certificate is not approved or validated by any authority. This
>   means one can create a certificate that says that their name is
>   Google. The only assurance is that this package name is reserved to
>   that user if no one had claimed it in the marketplace before, and any
>   subsequent updates to that package are given only to that user
>   (identified by that certificate).